# How does iOS connect a UI object to the view controller object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I'm new to iOS development and not sure how iOS connects a UI object to the underlying view controller object.  In Android the UI element has an id set in the designer and used in the view but I don't see the same in Xcode only the following (in the ViewController.swift which doesn't seem to connect to a specific UI element):

```
@IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
```

where as in Android I'd do the following in OnCreate()

```
statusLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.statusLabel);
```

Comment: It becomes reference when you ctrl-drag the a specific UIView element from Storyboard to your view controller.

Comment: Thanks to all for the quick responses.  I should be more explicit.  I have ctrl-dragged the control from the story board to the view controller but changed the variable name in the controller which caused an exception to be thrown.  So I was looking to find where I can edit the control name to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the variable name of the outlet once it's connected, Xcode 9.2 and higher has a refactor feature, which allows you to rename variables easily.

**Command + Click** on the variable name and then click **Rename...**.
[image: Refactor feature]

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of the `UIViewController` class has an underlying `UIView` property called `view`. When you are using interface builder, you can `ctrl+drag` the view you have added to create an `IBOutlet` which references the view whose properties you have modified in interface builder.

This creates the UI element and will add it as a subview of `UIViewController`'s `view` and allow you to access it directly in any of the `UIViewController`'s methods, or (assuming its not private) any instance of that `UIViewController`.

```
let myViewControllerInstance : ViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "main", bundle: nil)!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerStoryboardID")
myViewControllerInstance.myStatusLabel.text = "I can change the label's properties from any instance of the View Controller"
```

If you need to programmatically modify any properties of your `UIView` instance before the `ViewController` appears it is recommended to do so in `ViewDidLoad`.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        statusLabel.text = "My Status Label" //Accessing your UI element directly
    }
}
```

The alternative to using the storyboards approach would be to instantiate the view programmatically, set it's frame (or add constraints if using auto-layout), and add it as a subview.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {

    var myStatusLabel : UIView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        statusLabel = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubview(myStatusLabel)
        statusLabel.text = "This label was created progrommatically."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS you usually use Storyboards (or sometimes XIB files) to set up your user interface. In a storyboard/XIB you control-drag from your interface into your view controller's code to create or connect outlet links.

The storyboard/XIB is an XML file internally that describes the UI and the links to outlets. At the time the storyboard/XIB is loaded, the system connects the outlet and action links.

Comment: Thanks.  Is the xml file editable and if so where is it?  I changed the variable name which caused a disconnect.

Comment: It is editable, but I strongly advise against it. (The Interface Builder GUI is supposed to manage those files, and you run the risk of rendering your project unusable if you change something Xcode does not expect.) Go to the storyboard, disconnect the outlet link, and reconnect it. That should solve your problem.

Comment: So the connection inspector didn’t show any connections at all, I had 4 of them. I deleted the variables, readded the connections and still nothing. Exited Xcode and reopened the project to find the outlet and action connections there. This simple app now works.   I think Xcode might be a tad buggy though. Thanks again to all for the help.